# How to connect Android App to AWS Database

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services

Previously, my application did not connected to AWS Database. I want to change database connection to AWS Database. But i found some trouble. I think it was same like we connect AWS Database into a Website Application. But it really different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile apps usually don't connect to a database directly but do crud operations through an api like a webservice.

Comment: what is webservice/api example?

Comment: A webservice is an intermediate service which handles requests done by for example mobile apps to do crud operations (Create, Read, Update and Delete) on the database.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

That way so don't have to publish an update of your app when the connectionstring to your database changes, you can just change your webservice. Or when the structure of your database changes you could change your webservice to implement these changes without having to change and republish your mobile app. Also you should avoid having a connectionstring in your mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

So just create web_services and get data like normal https request in android app then handle received data with android apps logic